# Mac application without window

Tags: macos, statusbar, windowless

I've little knowledge in developing Mac window based application. When the app starts up, i don't want to show the window at all. I'm placing icon in status bar and on right clicking it will show options and one option is to see the window.
Can some one tell me how to hide the window when the app starts up?

Comment: You can also find a short introduction how to create a status bar application at http://www.jademind.com/blog/posts/how-to-create-a-mac-osx-status-bar-application

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In application xib, select the window object, and you will see "Visible at Launch" in Attributes Inspector.

Comment: xCode 6 has 'Is Initial Controller' checkbox attribute. Visible at launch is no longer helpful

Comment: thank heximal. "Visible at Launch" is really no longer helpful. Should disable 'Is Initial Controller' checkbox